# PFIncrementalStore. Can only use -performBlock: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue

Tags: core-data

I am trying to use PFIncrementalStore, http://sbonami.github.io/PFIncrementalStore/

After setting up as instruction, I get the following error at [context performBlock:^,

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can only use -performBlock: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue.'
```

Some internet search said, NSManagedObjectContext must be created with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType.

If I look up all "NSManagedObjectContext init" in PFIncrementalStore.m, I get two occurrence of

```
_backingManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]     initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
```

Why am I getting that error?  How should I edit PFIncrementalStore? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by replacing

```
_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
```

with

```
_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
```